# curl http handler for solarium solr error

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, solr, solarium

I am trying to use solarium to run php code which uses solr for indexing data , I have done on my system , and its working fine , But when I run on my collegue's system i get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Solarium\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'cURL is not available, install it to use the CurlHttp adapter' in 
/var/www/app/webroot/kl/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php:67
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/app/webroot/kl/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Configurable.php(77): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->init() 
#1 /var/www/app/webroot/kl/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php(484): Solarium\Core\Configurable->__construct() 
#2 /var/www/app/webroot/kl/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php(507): Solarium\Core\Client\Client->createAdapter() 
#3 /var/www/app/webroot/kl/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php(796): Solarium\Core\Client\Client->getAdapter() 
#4 /var/www/app/webroot/kl/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php(766): Solarium\Core\Client\Client->executeRequest(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), NULL) 
#5 /var/www/app/webroot/kl/ve in /var/www/app/webroot/kl/vendor/solarium/solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php on line 67
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: `cURL is not available, install it to use the CurlHttp adapter` Silly question: is cURL installed on your colleague's system?

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, it looks like the [cURL](http://php.net/cURL) extension is not installed on his system, so either [install it](http://php.net/curl.setup.php) if possible, or in case it's just disabled, [enable it](https://google.com/search?q=php+enable+extension), or simply use a different adapter.

https://github.com/basdenooijer/solarium#requirements

> **Requirements**
>
> Solarium only supports PHP 5.3 and up. It's highly recommended to have Curl enabled in your PHP environment. However if you don't have Curl available you can switch from using Curl (the default) to another client adapter. The other adapters don't support all the features of the Curl adapter.

**HTTP Adapter**

https://github.com/basdenooijer/solarium/blob/master/examples/6.1.4-http-adapter.php

```
...

// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

// set the adapter to http
$client->setAdapter('Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Http');

...
```

**PECL HTTP Adapter**

https://github.com/basdenooijer/solarium/blob/master/examples/6.1.2-pecl-http-adapter.php

```
...

// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

// set the adapter to peclhttp
$client->setAdapter('Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\PeclHttp');

...
```

**Zend HTTP Adapter**

https://github.com/basdenooijer/solarium/blob/master/examples/6.1.1-zend-http-adapter.php

```
...

// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

// set the adapter to zendhttp and get a zendhttp client instance reference
$client->setAdapter('Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\ZendHttp');
$zendHttp = $client->getAdapter()->getZendHttp();

// you can use any of the zend_http features, like http-authentication
$zendHttp->setAuth('user', 'password!', Zend_Http_Client::AUTH_BASIC);

...
```